# Grabbing system product keys

Tags: powershell, registry

So I'm trying to use the PS script found at http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-product-keys-of-local-83b4ce97#content to pull Windows product keys from my domain remotely.  However, when it hits a host it returns `Exception calling “OpenRemoteBaseKey” with “2″ argument(s): “The network path was not found”` instead of the product key.  It should also be noted that this works locally.  After poking around at the internals of the script, it seems like the offending line is

```
$remoteReg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine,$Computer)
```

Research (because I'm totally new to PoSH) indicates that this type of error gets thrown when remote registry access isn't working.  Trying to hook into the registry on my test target via regedit shows that I need to have `Windows Firewall: Allow inbound remote administration exception` set to enabled in Group Policy.  I set it and then pulled the updated policy down to the same result.  What other stuff might be getting in the way of my connection?

Comment: $Computer is the remote computer name

Comment: The `Remote Registry` service must be running on the remote computer.

Comment: That's it.  Now, I'm faced with the problem of Powershell truncating the key automatically to my prompt width, but that seems like a more common problem and should be easier.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using PSRemoting over using the remote registry. Assuming this is set up, all you would have to do is:

```
$computers = @('localhost')#list of computers
#unless you are currently logged in as a domain admin
# you will need to provide credentials
$cred = Get-Credential domain\administrator 
Invoke-Command -Credential $cred  -ComputerName $computers -ScriptBlock {
function Get-ProductKey{ 
       #from http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-product-keys-of-local-83b4ce97
    }
get-ProductKey
}| ft Computername,OSDescription,OSVersion,ProductKey
```

This will print out the following output:

```
Computername                  OSDescription                 OSVersion                     ProductKey
------------                  -------------                 ---------                     ----------
%name%                        Microsoft Windows 8 Pro       6.2.9200                      XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following command through powershell, ran it as admin:

```
wmic /user:jc1_admin /node:pc00202 os get "SerialNumber"
```